# Mongo query to find single doc based on status fieds with respect to other docs status

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongo query to find single doc based on status fields with respect to other docs status

**docs**

```
{
_id:some mongo id,
name : "test one",
status:"new",
created_at:datetime,
updated_at:datetime
}
{
_id:some mongo id,
name : "test two",
status:"new",
created_at:datetime,
updated_at:datetime
}
{
_id:some mongo id,
name : "test one",
status:"started",
created_at:datetime,
updated_at:datetime
}
```

I need to find one doc with status "new" if no doc with status "started"

**note**
we need to consider doc with status "started" if current time & updated_at difference less than 1 hr

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**:

```
  db.coll.aggregate(
   [
     { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { $and: [{ $eq: [ { $lte: [  {$divide: [{$subtract: [new Date(), "$updated_at"]}, 3600000]} , 1] }, true]}, { "status": "started" }] },
           then: "$$KEEP",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }
     },
     { $match: { "status": "new" } },
     {"$limit":1}
   ]
);
```

**Explanation**:

1st pipeline: If any document with our given condition matches, $redact keeps all fields at this current document/embedded document level, without further inspection of the fields.
Else all documents are pruned.

2nd pipeline: Out of all documents returned, match only with status new.

3rd pipeline: limit result to 1

Alternatively, you can also try to do this in two steps. 

Step 1: check if any docuemnt with above $cond exists or not

Step 2: then find one document with new status

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using? $switch was introduced in mongo 3.4

Comment: 3.2, any other options ? without upgrade mongodb.